# How to show a notification icon in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am building an android application where I am letting the users to sign in using google also. When they sign in using google and do not register themselves using the registration page then there are certain information which are left out.I also have a screen which updates the profile information of the user.
I want to set an icon on the home screen(kind of a bell icon) which displays that there are some notification and when the user click on that the button it tells that some information are left to be added and it redirects them to the update profile page.

The icon I want is like the notification icon(bell) in youtube.[image: youtube icon]

Is there any way I can do this?

EDIT :

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grdnt"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textColor="#2AF598"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/provide_food"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Do you have Food"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/need_food"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/provide_food"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Do you need Food"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deliver_food"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/need_food"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Do you want to Deliver Food"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.helping_hands_individual;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button provide, need,deliver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        provide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.provide_food);
        need = (Button)findViewById(R.id.need_food);
        deliver = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deliver_food);

        provide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Provide_food.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Note: I am not using any custom toolbar, neither am I using any toolbar, my theme for the application is: NoActionBar

Comment: Do you want an icon at the top, like this?
https://photos.app.goo.gl/yJHCwkReNdqWX1GPA

Comment: yes just like that

Comment: can you share your MainActivity code here? also, I wanted to know if you're are using custom toolbar or not, and then I can help with this.

Comment: I have Updated it. @Vijay

Comment: Since you're not using any type of toolbar we can not inflate a menu over it. The option at the top right corner comes from inflating the options menu.
The other workaround for this is to add a button in an activity itself and use an on-click listener on it.
You can change the background image of the button so that the user will know that he yet needs to finish signing up.

Comment: So, if I enable the toolbar I will be able to perform this operation?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with all three ways
1. Change the theme from NoAcitonBar to the Action bar (or the one you using) and then override onCreateOptionsMenu method inside MainActivity.
2. Use the NoActionBar theme and add your own Custom toolbar and into this toolbar add inflate the menu.
3.  Add the custom View (Image view or Button) and position is at the top right corner and change its icon according to the state you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to get that notification icon depending upon the theme you are using in your Activity.

**1. No.ActionBar Theme:** If you're not using any ActionBar or toolbar in your activity then you can create a View(ImageView or Button) in your Activity's layout file with Height and Width as same as the notification icon which is around 28dp and then position it at the top right corner of the screen. You can change the background image of the view according to the state you want.

**2. Create your own toolbar:** You can create your own toolbar and set the menu item in it. While creating the menu item make sure that you select `showAsAction="always"` this way your icon is always visible. here is a [link](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/toolbar) for the reference

**3.ActionBar Theme:** If you're using the action bar theme then you can create a menu file with one item like in Option 2 and then override the onCreateOptionsMenu and inflate then inflate your menu in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Notification notification  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
```